# variational calculus problem

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, it.information-theory, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-optimization

I have two functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ defined for $0\leq x \leq 1$.
Let $$L^HL = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1\end{array} \right].$$

Define $$R(x) = \log\left(1 + \frac{f_1^2(x)}{1+\int_x^1f_1^2(x)dx+\int_x^1f_2^2(x)dx}\right).$$

I need now to solve
$$\min_{f_1(x),f_2(x)} \mathrm{Tr}\left[L\left[\begin{array}{cc} \int_0^1 f_1^2(x)+f_2^2(x)dx & \int_0^1 f_1(x)f_2(x)dx \\\int_0^1 f_1(x)f_2(x)dx & \int_0^1 f_1^2(x)+f_2^2(x)dx\end{array}\right]L^H\right]$$
subject to
$$ \int_0^1 R(x)=C$$
for some positive value $C$.

Thanks

Comment: Should the bottom right entry of the matrix be something different?

Comment: Wherever you have $f_1^2(x)+f_1^2(x)$ in the matrix, you almost surely meant  $f_1^2(x)+f_2^2(x)$.  Right?

Comment: correct!sorry,both diagonal elements should be $f_1^2(x) + f_2^2(x)$

Comment: You write what $L^HL$ is, but not what $L$ is. If $L$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, then the expression inside $\min$ is also a matrix, right? But then, what do you want to minimize?

Comment: You've made this more complicated than you needed to:  Since $\mathrm{Tr}(ABC) = \mathrm{Tr}(BCA)$, it doesn't matter what the exact formula for $L$ is.  You are just trying to minimize $$M = 2\int_0^1\bigl(f_1(x)^2+\rho f_1(x)f_2(x) + f_2(x)^2\bigr)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ subject to the given constraint.  Now use Lagrange multipliers and derive the Euler-Lagrange equation.